# UPDATE sql query and get the updated field in one single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to update a value of a column using the codeigniter query function like this:

```
    $this->db->query("UPDATE table SET val = val + 1 WHERE name = 'xxxxx');
```

Is there any way to get the result of this update in the same query function? I have to do a select query in order to do it and it's dangerous because of the amount of users this application is managing.

If there is another query in between the update and the select, the result would not be correct.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using a transaction?

Comment: Were you considered using *autoincrement* field?

Comment: mysql

How can i use transactions in a codeigniter db->query function? It fails when I try it.

Comment: Sounds like it is some kind of counter for the row with `name=xxxx`, so an autoincrement doesn't look like it would help?

Comment: I cannot use an autoincrement field... :(

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

Use transaction and for update. This is an example from zend, which is a similar kind of db accessing thing:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$val = $db->select()->forUpdate()->from('table', 'val')->orderBy('val DESC')->limit(1)->query()->fetchColumn();
$db->update('table', 'val = '.($val+1), 'name = "xxx"');
$db->commit()
```

The for-update with the transaction prevents another query interfering.

Learn more about for update here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

and about codeigniter transactions here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html (thanks to @Nanne for that)